# Why is the generic type parameter inferred differently for an extended interface and for a type alias of an intersection of interfaces?

Tags: typescript, types, intersection, extends

In the following toy experiment (simplified from a real-world example), why is the generic type parameter inferred differently depending on whether the template is instantiated with an extended type or with an intersected type?

```
interface Base { b: number }
interface Extra { a: string }
interface Ext1 extends Extra { b: number }
type Ext2  = Base & Extra

// f returns a function that takes a T as input
const f = <T extends Base>(inp: T & Extra): ((arg: T) => void) => {
    return (arg: T) => console.log(inp.a + arg.b) 
}

const x1: Ext1 = { a: "x1", b: 1 }
const x2: Ext2 = { a: "y1", b: 2 } 

const f1 = f(x1) // T inferred to Ext1
const f2 = f(x2) // T inferred to Base, NOT Ext2 (why?)

const inp = { b: 3 }

// error Argument of type '{ b: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ext1'. Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: number; }' but required in type 'Ext1'.
const out1 = f1(inp) 

// ok since inp is of type Base
const out2 = f2(inp)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN7IEYBcyIArgLZ7TIC+AUKJLIigKIAeYUcyucRGnUAHMa9cNHhJk7MAEZkEDhBAATDNI5ce+IqQpU6YAJ4AHVhwBMyZAF40mFADINnOLVoB6D8hjIoEMBIoEHVuGBIQBDBgAHsQZDAACzgwBLgAawhQ5AAVZExkUBMSMFoEOIEfW2QAHjzFSFV1dCwAPgAKIqI85xkuAEoidva4KCFu-ttW5AA3GOAVSZtp7Fpra39A4OQRsYmp5HKQmIAbCAA6E5ihTpATc+4Aanyx87xJ2joyitS2WSIZPI7LwiAAiP6ggA0OmQ8joR0qbAsAMs1RByFBRlkUJhVmoyHcCNSMCBPnaf0mXlyhRAMGg-hUCRiLlk3xCxKsdhg5IslO8eVAdKgDKZ9iw0IAcgB5PIyKztADuiSMAH5+oSfjSTGiYQBmUSebz0mJQZAAQTG5GUqRivmMZmQAHJcIRiORKFAANw0R2FdQgGKpTAYYBCEBwPBnUUmUZwMgBKi2hKmFCOwGO87IAAKUBiZigxidcF9wHUZFLIZAIlAyYdzpheg93uovrwJT8EAAjiRgCKa-bU+nzmzKjESqSSbcTB9DcgYulkJWpEU-XO7SmxRARzaSpyfBYp-0gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you encountered here is not an issue with inference but rather a side-effect of elimination of redundant intersection members. Notice the `& Extra` in the `inp` type. When `f` is passed a variable of type `Ext2` at call site, the type of `inp` essentially becomes `Base & Extra & Extra`.

Since identical types are eliminated from intersections, the type of `inp` actually becomes `Base & Extra`, and the type parameter `T` is then inferred as `Base` as it satisfies both the `extends Base`. And, indeed, if you remove the intersection of `T` with `Extra`, you will observe correct inference:

```js
interface Base { b: number }
interface Extra { a: string }
interface Ext1 extends Extra { b: number }
type Ext2  = Base & Extra

// f returns a function that takes a T as input
const f = <T extends Base>(inp: T): ((arg: T) => void) => {
    return (arg: T) => console.log(inp.a + arg.b)
}

const x1: Ext1 = { a: "x1", b: 1 }
const x2: Ext2 = { a: "y1", b: 2 } 

const f1 = f(x1) // T inferred to Ext1
const f2 = f(x2) // T inferred to Ext2

const inp = { b: 3 }

const out1 = f1(inp) // error
const out2 = f2(inp) // error
```

With that out of the way, let's clear a small misconception. Extending from an `interface` works *similarly* to intersecting two interfaces, but they are *not the same*. `extends` means that the left-hand side type (interface) is a *subtype* (or, in other terms, is *narrower*), and the right-hand side type (interface) is a *supertype* (or is *wider*).

On the contrary, intersections create a *combination* of types. Take a look at the example below to see the crucial difference between `extends` and `&` in action:

```js
interface A { a: string, b: boolean }
interface B { a: number, b: boolean }
interface C extends A, B {} // error, cannot extend

type a = { a:string, b: boolean }
type b = { a:number, b: boolean }
type c = a & b; // no error, but 'a' is never
```

That is precisely why when you intersect the `Ext1` with `Extra`, nothing happens — there are no identical types to eliminate, only `Ext1` (a *subtype* of `Extra`) and `Extra` (a *supertype*).

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w65K0W)

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! Could clarify that in the event of removing `& Extra` from the argument type, we would also obviously have to remove `inp.a` in the printout but then the said effect can be seen. Apart from that, what you're saying both answers the question and is interesting :)

Comment: @fast-reflexes NP! I'd advise going for a type guard (f.e. `"a" in inp ? ... : ...`) or something similar. Unconditionally accessing `inp.a` when the type parameter is constrained to `Base` is, ofc, unsound. Looks like you have a trade-off between being stuck with subtyping with `extends` and requiring a type guard before accessing `inp.a` (CFA will do the rest).